# cx_Oracle ImportError Reason: image not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

When trying to run a script that uses `cx_Oracle` I'm getting an `ImportError`.

```
./runtests.py <args here>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/smeatonj/Development/.virtualenvs/djangopy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
  Referenced from: /Users/smeatonj/Development/.virtualenvs/djangopy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Advice elsewhere suggests exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which I've done. When I open a python shell and try to import `cx_Oracle` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the script was prefixed with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cx_Oracle
```

I think this prevents the shell from using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The fix is to execute the script with python directly:

```
python runtests.py
```

I'd be happy to edit this answer with additional information on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if someone knows more.